# Computed properties vs methods with shape classes

Tags: comparative-review, swift

I'd be interested in hearing what folk think are the pros and cons of the following two ways of writing classes like the following `Circle`, `Square` and `Rectangle` classes in Swift.

The first way has them extending a superclass (`ShapeSC`) with methods. The second has them implementing a protocol (`ShapeP`) with computed properties. 
Both are tested with identical code, and give identical results.

Note: I've copied the code directly from a playground where it was working, so hopefully you'll find it error-free.

**First way: subclasses extend a superclass and override "abstract" methods:**

```
import UIKit
import Darwin

class ShapeSC {
   let π = M_PI
   var area: Double
   var perimeter: Double

   init() {
      area = 0
      perimeter = 0
   }

   func calcArea() -> Double {
      return 0
   }

   func calcPerimeter() -> Double {
      return 0
   }


class Circle: ShapeSC {
   var radius: Double

   init(radius: Double) {
      self.radius = radius
   }

   override func calcArea() -> Double {
      return π * radius * radius
   }

   override func calcPerimeter() -> Double {
      return π * 2 * radius
   }
}

class Square: ShapeSC {
   var side: Double

   init(side: Double) {
      self.side = side
   }

   override func calcArea() -> Double {
      return side * side
   }

   override func calcPerimeter() -> Double {
      return 4 * side
   }
}

class Rectangle: ShapeSC {
   var width: Double
   var height: Double

   init(width: Double, height: Double) {
      self.width = width
      self.height = height
   }


   override func calcArea() -> Double {
      return width * height
   }

   override func calcPerimeter() -> Double {
      return 2 * width + 2 * height
   }

}

let c1 = Circle(radius: 10)
c1.calcArea()
c1.calcPerimeter()

let s1 = Square(side: 10)
s1.calcArea()
s1.calcPerimeter()

let r1 = Rectangle(width: 5, height: 5)
r1.calcArea()
r1.calcPerimeter()
```

**Second way: classes conform to a protocol and use computed properties:**

```
import UIKit
import Darwin

protocol ShapeP {
   var area: Double { get }
   var perimeter: Double { get }
}

class Circle: ShapeP {
   let π = M_PI
   var radius: Double

   init(radius: Double) {
      self.radius = radius
   }

   var area: Double {
      return π * radius * radius
   }

   var perimeter: Double {
      return π * 2 * radius
   }
}

class Square: ShapeP {
   var side: Double

   init(side: Double) {
       self.side = side
   }

   var area: Double {
      return side * side
   }

   var perimeter: Double {
      return 4 * side
   }
}

class Rectangle: ShapeP {
   var height: Double
   var width: Double

   init(height: Double, width: Double) {
      self.height = height
      self.width = width
   }

   var area: Double {
      return width * height
   }

   var perimeter: Double {
      return 2 * width + 2 * height
   }
}

let c1 = Circle(radius: 10)
c1.area
c1.perimeter

let s1 = Square(side: 10)
s1.area
s1.perimeter

let r1 = Rectangle(height: 5, width: 5)
r1.area
r1.perimeter
```

Comment: Syntax error maybe? The body of `ShapeSC` is not closed with a `}`

Answer (score 5):

#### Using a superclass

`ShapeSC` shouldn't be a superclass,
because it provides no useful implementation.
A shape with 0 area and perimeter doesn't make any sense.
Since there are no abstract classes in Swift,
`ShapeSC` cannot enforce sub-classes to override its methods.
So it's an outright dangerous approach,
as implementors may forget to replace the useless method with meaningful ones.

Btw, the `π` variable didn't belong in `ShapeSC`,
as it's only useful for `Circle`,
not by any other class in the hierarchy.

On the other hand,
it would have made sense to make `Square` extend `Rectangle`,
and inherit much of its implementation.

One small final note, I would write `Rectangle`'s `calcPerimeter` method as:

```
   override func calcPerimeter() -> Double {
      return 2 * (width + height)
   }
```

#### Using a protocol

If you notice,
writing it using a protocol automatically cleaned up some odd elements of the superclass variant:

- `π` is naturally defined in `Circle`, not somewhere else needlessly
- No more 0-area 0-perimeter objects, by design

Even the code is shorter.
There are no obvious downsides either, which is in stark contrast with the superclass variant.

#### Using a mixed hierarchy

Consider a mixed hierarchy, using protocols and inheritance where they make sense.
For example `Shape` should clearly be a protocol,
but `Rectangle` can be a class that specialized cases like `Square` can inherit from.
As you explore the shape universe,
there might be other cases in the hierarchy where a protocol might make sense.

Comment: Here is Square extending Rectangle (good idea - much better): 

class Square: Rectangle {
    
    init(side: Double) {
        super.init(width: side, height: side)
    }
}

Comment: @jim Yes, but you have to go much farther than just that.  I comment on this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What is `ShapeSC`?  What is `ShapeP`?  Why are we abbreviating things that cause me to ask questions and don't save you any time whatsoever?  What does the `SC` stand for?  What does the `P` stand for?  Can't we just write `Shape` and `ShapeProtocol`?

---

Please don't use `π` as a variable name.  Yes, it's cool that Xcode lets us use extended ASCII characters in our variable and method and class names now.  Will that still be cool when we have a smileyface-dog-wavingflag method name?  How many characters can you keep in memory?  You know, there will be people maintaining this code who are reduced to keeping `π` in their clipboard while editing your code because they can't figure out that it's <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.  Let's stick to the 26 alphabetical characters, upper and lower, and probably still not use single character variable names.

---

`Square` should inherit from `Rectangle`, or perhaps not even exist at all.  A square is a special case of a rectangle.  If it exists, it should inherit from rectangle.  We can enforce its squareness by adding a `didSet` method to both the `height` and `width` properties to make sure setting one updates the other.  We'd also add an initializer that takes just a single argument, and override the initializer which takes two arguments as a failable initializer which fails when the arguments aren't the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Like all code reviews, I start by recommending unit tests.  In this case, they would help you visualize what the code that consumes these interfaces would look like.  You sort of have that at the bottom of your code, but you just list the properties being used, not demonstrating actual usage nor are you proving your code works.

Obviously there's no substantial difference between the methods.  Both will compute just as quickly.  Both objects will behave the same in your consumer app.  The real difference is in readability: do these names convey to your user something important?

When viewed that way, you can decide if it is important to convey to your user that you will "Calc" the area.  If they are only interested in area, then "c1.CalcArea()" looks heavier than a simple property c1.area and might make someone think twice about calling it.  All of these examples are simple enough that computing them every time you call area isn't expensive. But if your area computation was huge (consider computing a heavily nested area of a detailed map) it might be deceptively simple to request .area every time it's needed instead of caching it temporarily for performance reasons.

Comment: For what it's worth, `area` versus `calcArea` is simply a naming difference.  The property *could* easily be called `calcArea` and the method could easily be called `area`.